# Automatically update the input field within a form, vue.js

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to search for elements using an input field within a form. I am passing a value from a component to another and the content changes but only after pressing enter. Is there a way to automatically update the list, after every new letter is typed?
Here is my code:

Parent(App):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header v-on:phrase-search="passPhrase" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from ...

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      searchedPhrase: ""
    };
  }
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      let temp_text = this.searchedPhrase;
      temp_text.trim().toLowerCase();

      return this.posts.filter(post => {
        return post.name.toLowerCase().match(temp_text);
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    passPhrase(phrase) {
      this.searchedPhrase = phrase;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child(Header):

```
<template>
<div class="child">
  <p>Search:</p>
    <form @submit.prevent="phrasePassed">
      <input type="text" v-model="phrase" />
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "search",
  data() {
    return {
      phrase: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    phrasePassed() {
      this.$emit("phrase-search", this.phrase);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

passPhrase() brings the value from the child to the parent and then filteredPosts() find appropriate elements. I suspect that the form might be guilty of this issue but I do not know precisely how to get rid of it and still be able to pass the value to the parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the child you use `submit` event which called on enter. you should use `@input` on the input itself. and btw you didnt need even to declare pharse in the `data` because you didnt use it in the child. you just pass it up

you it like so

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Search:</p>
    <form>
      <input type="text" @input="phrasePassed">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "search",
  methods: {
    phrasePassed(e) {
      this.$emit("phrase-search", e.target.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for :)